# I want to read a array value inside factory in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-grid

I am trying to read value in array in factory but I am unable to do so. I am using ng-grid and when I click on one row I get selecteditems list which I pass in another controller where I call a factory service in which I pass that as a parameter but  that parameter in the factory stays as array and when I read it using index it shows blank.
My code is as below -

```
myNgApp.controller('MyGrid', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.mySelections = [];
    $scope.mySelItems = [];
    $scope.myData = [{ Reference: 12, Customer: "fff", Title: "sd", Task: "Enter Details", Received: "Today", Due: "01/09/2014" },
    { Reference: 7899, Customer: "eee", Title: "dsd", Task: "Enter Details", Received: "Yesterday", Due: "05/09/2014" }];

    $scope.gridOptions = {
        data: 'myData',
        checkboxHeaderTemplate: '<input class="ngSelectionHeader" type="checkbox" ng-model="allSelected" ng-change="toggleSelectAll(allSelected)"/>',
        selectWithCheckboxOnly: true,
        showSelectionCheckbox: true,
        selectedItems: $scope.mySelections,
        multiSelect: true,
        columnDefs: [{ field: 'Reference', displayName: 'Reference', width: '*' }, { field: 'Customer', displayName: 'Customer', width: '**' }, { field: 'Title', displayName: 'Title', width: '***' }, { field: 'Task', displayName: 'Task', width: '***' }, { field: 'Received', displayName: 'Received', width: '**' }, { field: 'Due', displayName: 'Due', width: '**' }],
        showGroupPanel: true,
        enableCellSelection: false,
        enableRowSelection: true,
        enableCellEditOnFocus: false,
        enablePinning: true,
        showColumnMenu: true,
        showFilter: true,
        enableColumnResize: true,
        enableColumnReordering: true,
        maintainColumnRatios: true,
        afterSelectionChange: function () {

            angular.forEach($scope.mySelections, function (item) {
                if ($scope.mySelItems.length == 0) {
                    $scope.mySelItems.push(item.Title)
                }
                else {
                    $scope.mySelItems[0] = item.Title
                }
            });
        }

    };

}]);


    myNgApp.factory('myPreviewDataService', function () {

    return function (x) {

        var arr = [x, "Apple", "Banana", "Orange"];

        return arr
    };
});

    myNgApp.factory('myPreviewTplService', function () {
    return function () {

        return '<div><div class="ngPreviewItems" ng-repeat="item in items">{{item}}</div></div>';
    };
});

myNgApp.directive('showPreview', function ($compile) {
    return {
        scope: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var el;

            attrs.$observe('template', function (tpl) {
                if (angular.isDefined(tpl)) {
                    // compile the provided template against the current scope
                    el = $compile(tpl)(scope);

                    // stupid way of emptying the element
                    element.html("");

                    // add the template content
                    element.append(el);
                }
            });
        }
    };
});

myNgApp.controller('myPreviewController', function ($scope, myPreviewDataService, myPreviewTplService) {
    //$scope.showContent = function () {

    $scope.items = myPreviewDataService($scope.mySelItems);
    $scope.template = myPreviewTplService();
    //};
});
```

here $scope.mySelItems is from ng grid controller that gets updated when we select a checkbox.
What I get is an array but I am unable to read its content, when I display the array as it is it gets displayed like ["test"] but when I try to read it x[0] in myPreviewDataService factory or by $scope.mySelItems[0] in myPreviewController then I get blank. I am not able to figure out why this is happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve it. In **myPreviewDataService** factory I changed the array elements from string to array

```
var arr = [x, "Apple", "Banana", "Orange"];
```

changed to

```
var arr = [x, ["Apple"], ["Banana"], ["Orange"]];
```

and in **myPreviewTplService** factory I changed `{{item}}` to `{{item[0]}}`

it worked.

*P.S I think we can also use ng switch based on condition in **myPreviewTplService** factory based on the type of item, I tried to do it but I was not able to do so and worked with my earlier solution.*